# jQuery page fade script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a script that, when I click a nav-link, checks what class is attached to that specific link, then hides the current page and displays the page that also contains that specific class.

This script currently switches between 2 pages rather than checking for a page with a class, but I'm sure it'll be simple to add that later (1 line of code).

```
(function () {
pages = ["home", "about", "portfolio", "misc", "inquire"];

//request = window.location.hash.substring(1);

//Finding page corresponding to clicked link
function SetRequest (link, pages)
{
    lookingFor =  ".home";

    for (var i in pages)
    {
        if (link.hasClass(("." + pages[i]).toString()))
        {
            lookingFor = pages[i];
        }
    }

    return ("." + lookingFor).toString();
}

//Hiding all other pages, showing page needed
function ShowCurrentPage (page, pages, lookingFor)
{
    for (var i in pages)
    {
        if (page.hasClass(lookingFor))
        {
            $(".page.current").animate({opacity: 0});
            $(".page.current").removeClass("current");
            $(".page").animate({opacity: 1});
            $(".page").addClass("current");
        }
    }
}

$(".nav-link a").click(function(){
    ShowCurrentPage($(this), pages, SetRequest($(this), pages));
});
})();
```

Comment: could you link it with the html ?

Comment: [Edit] your question to, well, ask a question.  If you're just looking for code review, you can't get it here.  Also, we're not a forum, so try to write in a more formal, just-state-the-facts way.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3gnnxder/1/

Comment: @Tom **YES!** Thanks for cleaning everything up, again, I'm new and VERY used to C# at this point. Everything is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a loop. Just do something like this:

```
function switchPage(lookingFor)
{
    var lookingForDom = $('' + lookingFor); // I assume that lookingFor carries full selector either id or css based
    if (lookingForDom.length > 0) // We've found one
    {
        $(".page.current").removeClass("current").animate({opacity: 0});
        lookingForDom.addClass("current").animate({opacity: 1});
    }
}
```

There's also easy way to obtain needed page name, just keep it inside some attribute of link that's beeing clicked and retrive it. Href is designed place for such things (but you need to use id on page-div then). So js would be:

```
$('.nav-link a').click(function(){ switchPage($(this).attr('href')); });
```

Also remember to registrate your events either with inside $(document).ready function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".nav-link a").click(...);
});
```

Full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function switchPage(lookingFor)
            {
                var lookingForDom = $('' + lookingFor); // I assume that lookingFor carries full selector either id or css based
                if (lookingForDom.length > 0) // We've found one
                {
                    $(".page.current").removeClass("current").animate({opacity: 0});
                    lookingForDom.addClass("current").animate({opacity: 1});
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                // Initial switch to hide other pages
                $('.page').css({ opacity: 0 });
                switchPage('#pageA');

                $('.links a').click(function(){ switchPage($(this).attr('href')); });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pageA" class="page">I'm page A</div>
        <div id="pageB" class="page">I'm page B</div>
        <div id="pageC" class="page">I'm page C</div>

        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="#pageA">Go to page A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageB">Go to page B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageC">Go to page C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually do need the loop to get the stored class from the nav-link corresponding to what page is to appear. Also this site is a one-page design, content fades in and out based on the links that are clicked.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something but check the code I've posted in my answer. It does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple code that does the trick : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/advjeN

html :

```
<nav class="nav-link">
  <a  class="aa" href="#">FIRST LINK</a> 
  <a class="bb" href="#">SECOND LINK</a> 
</nav>

<div class="pages">
<div class="aa page red"></div>


<div class="bb page blue hide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS  :

```
.page{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px; 
  margin : 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.red{ background-color: red;}
.blue{background-color: blue;}
.hide{ display: none;}
```

and jquery :

```
(function () {

$(".nav-link a").click(function(){
    var myclass = '.' + $(this).attr('class');
    $('.pages').children().hide();
    $(myclass).fadeIn();
});
})();
```

If put them all in a " pages " div so you can hide them all easely, but if they all at least one class that's the same for all you can simply do $(myclass).hide();

Comment: i forgot to save the changes, the link is now working ^^ 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/advjeN